# Is there a way to wipe a VirtualBox drive on exit?

Tags: virtualization

In VirtualBox, is there a way to wipe the virtual drive of a Guest OS upon exiting/shutting down that OS?

If not, is there any other way to reaching that goal without doing it manually?

Comment: Use drive encryption and forget the key.

Comment: You mean a particular drive / partition?  Or the entire drive including the OS?

Comment: I mean the virtual drive that is assigned to the Guest OS. Basically, I want it to be a 'fresh' OS every time I start it up again.

Comment: If you don't care whether the wipe is on shutdown or on startup, it's possible.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: Have you considered trying to make a snapshot and then have it restore to that snapshot on shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset your VirtualBox virtual machine to a "fresh" OS on each startup, the easiest way is to install the OS and configure it as you like, then set the disk as "immutable":

1. From the VirtualBox Manager, select "File" -> "Virtual Media Manager".
2. Select the virtual disk image for your virtual machine.
3. Click "Modify".
4. Select "Immutable" and click "OK".

Now, every time you start the VM up, the disk will be reset to its current state.  You can temporarily suspend the reset-on-startup by taking a snapshot of the VM; deleting the snapshot will restore the reset behavior.

Note that this wipes on startup, not shutdown.  If you're doing the wipe for anti-forensic reasons, you'll need to find another option.

Comment: VirtualBox will not write to that .vdi file anymore, but it will create a different file and write all of the changes to that file instead.  So this answer is only half of what OP is looking for.  `without doing it manually`

Comment: @Blerg, it will create a different file, write the changes to it, *and delete that file the next time you start the virtual machine*.  It's exactly what the OP is looking for, except that the wipe takes place at next startup rather than at shutdown.  I'm using exactly this system right now to maintain a bunch of VMs for software-testing purposes.

Comment: You're right, I seem to have a few VMs with immutable drives that are glitched and don't delete any changes after a shutdown and power on, (they don't have snapshots either).  Not a complaint though, those are dev test beds and having them like that is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Two words my friend, “Live CD.”

Why bother with a drive at all if you’re not going to keep anything between uses? Many flavors of Linux come with LiveCD versions of the full OS that you can use to your hearts content. Shutdown/Kill the VM and all of that goes away, just like you want.

No need to create a virtual disk at all.  The only time it will write to the hard drive would be if your host OS swaps some of the memory to your pagefile, (but that's another issue).

If you think a live CD would be slow due to the CD read speed? Don’t burn it onto a CD. Run the ISO from your hard drive and it’s the same read speed as the hard drive.

Comment: A liveCD's no good if you're doing something that requires a full OS, such as testing software on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

While you are not being 100% clear on what OS you are using and even what the broad purpose of the setup is, if you are using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) already—and using it in a way in which you need a clean guest OS system on demand—why not use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) to script the build, control and even destroy the system.

On a most basic level—for example—you could do the following to create your initial guest OS. In this example it creates Ubuntu 14.04:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
```

That will download the initial system image used to create the Vagrant box which is basically just a VirtualBox. Then when it’s downloaded just run this command to start the system:

```
vagrant up
```

Connect to the guest OS like this:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Stop the Vagrant instance like this:

```
vagrant halt
```

And then—the key for your needs—would be to run this command to destroy the Vagrant box:

```
vagrant destroy
```

And since your system already has downloaded the Vagrant image for `ubuntu/trusty64`, you can then just run `vagrant up` again.

That is the most basic level of setup. But the nice thing about Vagrant is you can easily create provisioning scripts that can customize the machine each time it’s built. That way instead of creating a “vanilla” guest OS, you could have it customized to fit your needs each time you launch the system via `vagrant up`. And when your done, `vagrant destroy` wipes all signs of the system away.

Just so you know, `vagrant destroy` doesn’t “wipe” the virtual hard disk as much as it just deletes the file. But honestly, what would the benefit be of “wiping” a virtual disk image when it can just be deleted and recreated on demand?